# d3.js focus + context via brushing multiple paths not showing up

Tags: d3.js, focus, data-visualization

I referred to this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777518/having-trouble-drawing-d3-js-focuscontext-via-brushing-chart-with-multiple-path) for some code but for some reason on my chart, the chart disappears when I try to zoom in. 
I tried putting the code and the data in this [Vida document](https://vida.io/documents/szduwf97AzzhcS3mp) but the visualization won't show up altogether, and I still can't figure out the issue there.
Thanks for the help!

```
svg {
font: 10px sans-serif;
}

path {
fill:none;
stroke:white;
stroke-width:2px;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #CCC;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.brush .extent {
stroke: #fff;
fill-opacity: .125;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.path_H2O {
stroke:green;
}
.path_OH- {
stroke:red;
}
.path_Ca3SiO5 {
stroke:yellow;
}
```

---

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 40},
margin2 = {top: 630, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
width = 1600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
height2 = 700 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
x2 = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
.x(x2)
.on("brush", brush);


var area = function (Concent) {
return d3.svg.area()
.interpolate("step")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.Time); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d[Concent]); });
};
var area2 = function (Concent) {
return d3.svg.area()
.interpolate("step")
.x(function(d) { return x2(d.Time); })
.y0(height2)
.y1(function(d) { return y2(d[Concent]); });
};
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
.attr("id", "clip")
.append("rect")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

var myfunc = function(Time, data){

color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Time"; }));

 data.forEach(function(d){
      var y0 = 0; });
       /* d.concent = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
        d.total = d.concent[d.concent.length - 1].y1;});
      dataset=data;*/
      console.log(Time, data);

x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.Time; })));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.H2O; }))]);
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain());


focus.selectAll('path')
    .data(['H2O', 'OH-', 'Ca3SiO5'])
  .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
    .attr('d', function (col) {
      return area(col)(data);
    })
    .attr('class', function (col) {
      return "path_" + col + " data";
    });

focus.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

focus.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

  context.selectAll('path')
     .data(['H2O', 'OH-', 'Ca3SiO5'])
  .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', function (col) {
      return area2(col)(data);
    })
    .attr('class', function (col) {
      return "path_" + col;
    });

context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
  .call(xAxis2);

context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x brush")
  .call(brush)
.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("y", -6)
  .attr("height", height2 + 7);

function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    focus.selectAll("path.data").attr("d", function (col) { return area(col)(data); });
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
};

var data= d3.json([
{
"Time":0,
"H2O":0.7223999972,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775999921,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":0,
"H3SiO4-":0,
"Ca++":0,
"CaOH+":0,
"OH-":0,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0,
"H2O":0.7223999972,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775999921,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":0,
"H3SiO4-":0,
"Ca++":0,
"CaOH+":0,
"OH-":0,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.1011666667,
"H2O":0.722445376,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775546219,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":1.66E-006,
"H3SiO4-":0.0007145257,
"Ca++":0.0021455429,
"CaOH+":3.01E-006,
"OH-":0.0035762526,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.2025,
"H2O":0.7224635218,
"Ca3SiO5":0.277536476,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":5.77E-006,
"H3SiO4-":0.000996856,
"Ca++":0.0029978343,
"CaOH+":1.00E-005,
"OH-":0.0049973131,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.3038333333,
"H2O":0.7224757574,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775242411,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":1.19E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.001183896,
"Ca++":0.0035669817,
"CaOH+":2.03E-005,
"OH-":0.005946632,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.4051666667,
"H2O":0.722485082,
"Ca3SiO5":0.277514916,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":1.92E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0013237783,
"Ca++":0.0039957417,
"CaOH+":3.31E-005,
"OH-":0.0066624743,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.5065,
"H2O":0.7224926814,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775073166,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":2.77E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0014351806,
"Ca++":0.0043407829,
"CaOH+":4.80E-005,
"OH-":0.0072388754,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.611,
"H2O":0.7224993205,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775006773,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":3.68E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0015308949,
"Ca++":0.0046383714,
"CaOH+":6.48E-005,
"OH-":0.0077369817,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.7155,
"H2O":0.7225050948,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2774949035,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":4.60E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0016128709,
"Ca++":0.0048938526,
"CaOH+":8.27E-005,
"OH-":0.0081655806,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.82,
"H2O":0.7225102312,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2774897666,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":5.54E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0016845349,
"Ca++":0.0051181417,
"CaOH+":0.0001016937,
"OH-":0.0085426217,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.9245,
"H2O":0.722514876,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2774851215,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":6.52E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0017480743,
"Ca++":0.0053181429,
"CaOH+":0.0001216663,
"OH-":0.0088794869,
"Vacancy":"0"
};
],myfunc);
```

For the full dataset, please refer to the vida document I posted. Thanks!

Comment: I get this console error when attempting to load the page: `ReferenceError: Time is not defined at drawD3Document (eval at <anonymous>...`. You should check the complete error message.

Comment: Hmm interesting I don't get that console error with my original code but I had to modify it on the vida document...would posting my original code help?

Comment: It may help us narrow down the problem.

Comment: Okay I added most of the code, if the part that reads the data is funky, it's because I put the data in a different file and then had the code line: var data=d3.json("file_name.json, myfunc);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my efforts here since it is easier to type all that is needed in a greater box, if nothing else. I created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p7E5n/) to help us out. A few points:

1. I had to change the variable/myfunc strategy because it was not working. You will need to tell me if this actually worked. The lines are pretty flat but your data seems to show little variation in magnitude and perhaps some tweak in the scaling may help.
2. You were calling `brush` but your function is called `brushed`...that change was enough to activate the brush to do its job.

Well, let's see what you say. I hope this helps.

Comment: Well the dataset is actually very huge, so in the entire dataset there is a lot of variation in magnitude. (I believe the entire dataset was on the Vida?) I was hoping that I didn't have to copy and paste my entire dataset into my code and instead just read it from an outside source, but I will try. And oops with the name, that's probably it then.

Comment: Yes, I hear you about the data. As an FYI, [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) is a nice play area that facilitates using data files. And, yes, perhaps in the end it all boils down to applying the right function name.

Comment: It looks like it's the implementation of data and not the function name -sigh- Oh d3 why do you have to do this to me...
I'm going to try to mess around with other data formats to see if they do the same thing. But thank you for your help!

Comment: YMW. Yes, d3 can be a trip...but please let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Hi! I just wanted to let you know that I solved the data file problem by adding curly brackets around the whole file and "data": before the first square bracket, so now I can call the data from the code and not have to paste it in.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. Are you saying that you are now accessing your data file using `d3.json()`?

Comment: Yup! With the command d3.json ("data.json", function (error, Json) { And all the code after it