# d3js multi-line chart with focus+context zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, linechart

I am working on a multi-series line chart using d3.js and I am attempting to implement the focus and context zoom as seen in this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367). I have converted the area chart in the example to a line chart with a single series but I cannot figure out how to extend it to allow multiple series.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brushed);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); }); // single series?

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y2(d.price); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

d3.csv("trends.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);
});

function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.select(".line").attr("d", line);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}

function type(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.price = +d.price;
  return d;
}
```

I was successful in building a multi-line chart without the focus+context zoom feature, but I would really like to get the zoom piece working if possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://codepen.io/lesliepeng/pen/jGnue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming from your data that you have multiple series for price, you would have to change `d.price` to `d[price]`. Did you check this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777518/having-trouble-drawing-d3-js-focuscontext-via-brushing-chart-with-multiple-path)? I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: This is this solution I was looking for! I promise I tried searching before I posted... :)

Comment: Haha it's fine! I made a similar visualization and it took me time to find that valuable post before.